# Can we use Trigger in Gitlab community edition

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

Can we use trigger in Gitlab community edition? I receive an error while trying to configure multi project pipeline.

Here is my code:

```
stages:
    - test

testing:
    stage: test
    script:
        - echo "Parent pipeline is working"
    trigger:
        - project: testgroup/childproject
        - branch: master
```

Error: jobs:testing config contains unknown keys: trigger

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share version of runner that you are running this code ? Community Edition of Gitlab allows only from 12.8.

Additionally:

1. Remember that jobs with trigger are compatible with script section
2. Do not use " - " before project and branch elements

Reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/multi_project_pipelines.html#trigger-job-configuration-keywords